# Batch for searching and deleting folders and archives

Tags: batch-file

I need help with the next problem.
I have 2 directories D1 and D2, both with a tree of subdir and files. Both are similar, but D1 has more files than D2, those are junk-files.

I would want a batch to:

1. Searching through D1 and list everything.
2. Compare to D2 and, IF NOT EXIST delete from D1.
3. Make an echo >> log.txt of which files/folders where deleted.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: There are numerous free file managers that offer comparison of two directories. Depending on circumstances it may be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

First check the folders (sorting reverse to avoid current folders already being erased)

```
@Echo off &Setlocal EnableDealyedExpansion
Set "D1=Q:\Test\2017\08\"
Set "D2=C:\Test\2017\08\"

For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S/AD ^| Sort /r') Do (
    Set "ThisDirD1=%%A"
    Set "ThisDirD2=!ThisDirD1:%D1%=%D2%!"
    if Not Exist "!ThisDirD2!" (
        Echo Deleting !ThisDirD1! as !!ThisDirD2! doesn't exist
        Echo RD /Q /Y "!ThisDirD1!"
    )
)
```

If the output looks OK remove the echo in front of the`RD`command.

### For the remaining files repeat the same procedure.

```
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S/A-D ') Do (
    Set "ThisFileD1=%%A"
    Set "ThisFileD2=!ThisFileD1:%D1%=%D2%!"
    if Not Exist "!ThisFileD2!" (
        Echo Deleting !ThisFileD1! as !!ThisFileD2! doesn't exist
        Echo Del "!ThisFileD1!"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, LotPings, but this bat only removes directories, and I want to move direcrories and/or files.

Comment: **For the remaining files repeat the same procedure** isn't that difficult to unnderstand - at least I thought so - till now. Well, you want to be spoon fed. Be it so, here it is with a lullaby. Don't wake up and think yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. And I'm sorry for upset you. Have a nice day. :)